# Django Rest Framework JWT - Custom Payload with Extend User

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have an Extended User with sample serializers (Profile is Extend User, not Abstract User)

```
 {
    "id": 3,
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/demo/",
    "username": "demo",
    "first_name": "First",
    "last_name": "Demo",
    "profile": {
        "gender": null,
        "location": "Sa Pa",
        "date_of_birth": null,
        "job_title": null,
        "phone_number": null,
        "fax_number": "",
        "website": "",
        "intro": "",
        "bio": "",
        "interested_in": null,
        "languages": null,
        "quotes": null,
        "nickname": null
    }
}
```

How can I custom payload with **all above fields** and get it with `axios`?
Now it just get payload:

```
authUser:Object
email:"test@gmail.com"
exp:1509183691
user_id:1
username:"First Demo"
token:"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImxlY29uZ3RvYW4iLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJlbWFpbCI6ImRyYWZ0bGlnb25ncXVhbjdAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA5MTgzNjkxfQ.KSEp-7g-SGDbqfspedNwkT1rABFi0UQ45yKDJDTX2zA"
```

I followed with this link: [#145](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/145) but isn't work
Please help me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I did:

- create your own `jwt_response_payload_handler`:

  ```
  from your_serializers import UserSerializer

  def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
      return {
          'token': token,
          'user': UserSerializer(user, context={'request':request}).data
      }
  ```
- put your custom response payload handler into your `settings.py` file:

  ```
  JWT_AUTH = {
      ...,                
      'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'path_to.jwt_response_payload_handler',
      ...
  }
  ```

When you login you get back `token` and `user` with your serialized data.

Comment: What tool I can check if payload is get success or not @Gabriel?

Comment: I am using django rest framework browsable api, just run the server locally and go to your `localhost:8000/your_login_url` you'll get a nice form where you can login and check the response.

Comment: how do i manage if user changes the password, the old token will be valid right